# Animate sine wave, fixed start and end points

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, sine-wave

I have a sine wave in my canvas that is animated, swaying left and right. What I am trying to achieve is that the start and end points stay fixed. How to achieve that?

Here is the [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/BeKmeO)

```js
function start() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawCurves(context, step);

  step += 5;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
}

var step = -4;

function drawCurves(ctx, step) {
  var width = ctx.canvas.width;
  var height = ctx.canvas.height;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(66,44,255)";

  var x = 4;
  var y = 0;
  var amplitude = 20;
  var frequency = 90;
  while (y < height) {
    x = width / 2 + amplitude * Math.sin((y + step) / frequency);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    y++;
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body onload="start()">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="2000"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've changed the size of your canvas because I wanted to be able to see it. You can change it back to what you need.

I've done 2 things:

1. The  frequency has to be  `var frequency = height / (2 * Math.PI);` or  `var frequency = height / (4 * Math.PI);`. The divider has to be a multiple of 2 * Math.PI
2. I translate the context the opposite direction the same amount: `ctx.translate(-amplitude * Math.sin(step / frequency), 0);`

If you need a more subtile oscillation play with the amplitude.

In my code there is a commented out `ctx.closePath()` Please uncomment this line to see clearly that the sine-wave stay fixed in the center. I hope this is what you were asking.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


function start() {

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawCurves(context, step);

  step += 5;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
}

var step = -4;

function drawCurves(ctx, step) {
  var width = ctx.canvas.width;
  var height = ctx.canvas.height;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(66,44,255)";

  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var amplitude = 10;
  var frequency = height / (2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-amplitude * Math.sin(step / frequency), 0);
  while (y < height) {
    x = width / 2 + amplitude * Math.sin((y + step) / frequency);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    y++;
  }
  //ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

start();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: wheat;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE

In the case you need to use several curves you can do it like this:

I'm putting all the functionality for drawing the wave in a function `drawWave` that takes the amplitude and the trigonometric function to be used (sin or cos) as arguments:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = ctx.canvas.width;
var height = ctx.canvas.height;
var step = -4;

function start() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  drawWave(10,"sin");
  drawWave(10,"cos");
  drawWave(5,"sin");
  
  step += 5; 
}


  
function drawWave(amplitude,trig){
  // trig is the trigonometric function to be used: sin or cos
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(66,44,255)";

  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  //var amplitude = 10;
  var frequency = height / (2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-amplitude * Math[trig](step / frequency), 0);
  while (y < height) {
    x = width / 2 + amplitude * Math[trig]((y + step) / frequency);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    y++;
  }

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

start();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: wheat;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you that is what I was asking! Maybe you can help me further, the end effect I am trying to achive is this (https://riteshkukreja.github.io/sine-wave/). At the moment all waves are doing the exact same thing, I am having trouble changing the speed and the direction of each wave! You can see the updates in my Code Pen provided in the initial question. Thank you!

Comment: Genius! Is there a way to style closePath(), like add a different width and color?

Comment: `closePath()`? I'm not sure I understand you. If you want to have different color waves you can add a third argument to the `drawWave` function: the color. And you can use this color for the  `strokeStyle`

Comment: The waves are fine! But if I add closePath(), it draws a straight line from top to bottom right? And that is the line where I would like to change the styling! Does that make sense?

Comment: In this case for straight line you may add another wave with amplitude = 0:

Comment: Thank you for the input, I realised I was only making more complicated when I simply implemented what I needed with an ::after element! I noticed with your solution, using the step the speed of the waves changes depending on the performace capabilities of the device! Now I am trying and wondering if its posible to do it with requestAnimationFrame timestamp (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), so its constant on all devices!

Comment: I've used your code, including the step. The `requestAnimationFrame timestamp` would be a different question

Answer (score 4):

GLSL version

Because uv-coordinates in this fragment shader varies from 0 to 1 it is very simple to reach the goal, you only need wave frequency divisable by pi.

```js
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let pid = gl.createProgram();
shader(`attribute vec2 v;void main(void){gl_Position=vec4(v.xy,0.,1.);}`,gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
shader(document.querySelector(`script[type="glsl"]`).textContent,gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'resolution');
let time = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(time, t/500);
  gl.uniform2f(resolution, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="600" id="canvas"/>
<script type="glsl">
precision highp float;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void) {
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
  vec2 p = 20.*uv - 10.;
  vec3 f = vec3(0.);
  f+=pow(abs(p.x+5.*sin(time*2.)*sin(uv.y*6.28*2.)+cos(uv.y*11.)),-0.8)*vec3(.5,.0,.5);
  f+=pow(abs(p.x+4.*sin(time*3.)*sin(uv.y*6.28*.5)+cos(uv.y*21.)),-0.8)*vec3(.5,.5,.0);
  f+=pow(abs(p.x+3.*sin(time*5.)*sin(uv.y*6.28*1.)+cos(uv.y*17.)),-0.8)*vec3(.0,.5,.5);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(f, 1.);  
}
</script>
```